# Why doesn't the program stop when product = 9?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

The program is supposed to print out 3 , 6 and 9 then stop and display "End Of Program Reached" but goes on to print 3,6,9 and 12. How can that be resolved? Sample Code follows:

```
int x = 1;
int mul = 3;
int product = 0;
while (product < 10) {
    product = mul * x;
    System.out.println(product);
    x++;
}
System.out.println("End Of Program Reached");
```

Comment: So when `product` is `9` you don't want to iterate again, right? Now take a look at your loop condition.

Comment: There is an elementary logical error in your code. Do a dry run and I think you will figure out why it is happening. As figuring out errors is a stepping stone of programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `product` value that you're printing is not the one you're testing for in the `while` loop. The 1st `while` check is for product = 0.

Swap the `System.out.println(product);` and `product = mul * x;` statements and you'll likely understand.

Comment: Stepping through the program with a debugger in your IDE (if you are using one) is often a helpful task for understanding what is going on and is a useful skill to have when developing more advanced code.  Particularly, watching the value of product each time the `while` condition is evaluated would show you why Dan's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 1;
int mul = 3;
int product = 0;
while (product < 10) {
product = mul * x;
System.out.println(product);
x++;
}
System.out.println("End Of Program Reached");
```

If you try run this:

**in first iteration**

x = 1; mul=3; product=0;

Product < 10 i.e 0<10 hence goes into the loop.

Now product = x*mul; i.e product=3
x++;

**in second iteration:**

since 3<10 again goes into loop.

x = 2; mul=3; product=3;

Now product= x*mul=3*2= 6
and x++;

**in third loop:**

x=3 ;mul=3; product=6

Now product= 3*3 =9
x++;

**in fourth iteration:**

since 9<10 again goes into loop

x=4 ;mul=3; product=9

Now product= 3*4 =12
x++;

**fifth iteration:**

x=5 ;mul=3; product=12

now product>10 hence does not go into loop.

Hence prints 3 6 9 12

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your product is only checked if it is less than 10, after product has reached 12. e.g when x = 3 product=9, so it runs your loop again, after the next iteration when x = 4 and product = 12, this when your while loop sees that product > 10.
try this:

```
int x = 1 ;
int mul = 3;
int product = 0;
while (product < 9) {
    product = mul * x;
    System.out.println(product);
    x++;
}
System.out.println("End Of Program Reached");
```

by changing your while loop to

```
while (product < 9)
```

product reaches 9, then breaks the loop.